# Table cell event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a while stuck with this code and don't know what's wrong!
this jQuery code function is for a single web page application of a Game.
I need to change a table cell `background-color` by clicking on it but it doesn't work:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    var y, x, cellColor;
    //console.log("tata");

    $("#sizePicker").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function makeGrid(y, x) {
        y = Number($("#inputHeight").val());
        x = Number($("#inputWeight").val());
        $("#pixelCanvas tr").remove();
        for (i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            $("#pixelCanvas").append("<tr class='vertical'></tr>");
        }
        for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            $(".vertical").append("<td class='cell' ></td>");
        }
        $("#pixelCanvas tr td").css("background-color", "red");
    });

    $("#pixelCanvas tr td").click(function() {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that when you bind a click event to the table cells, those cells are not created yet. Try binding a click event to the body and use the `"#pixelCanvas tr td"` selector to filter event consumers: instead of `$("#pixelCanvas tr td").click` write the following:

```
$("body").on("click", "#pixelCanvas tr td", function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

Comment: I had this idea too but I wasn't quite sure about it. Your solution actually worked very well for me. Thank you very much for helping, man.

Comment: Another thing: I think you missed something when you edited my code. The last )}; was the closing for the ready function so it's needed not a wrong one. Thnks again.

Comment: @Ahmed I was glad to help! Sorry if I missed something while editing.. but all I did was indentation, I didn't remove any brackets. The last `});` now closes the `ready` function

Comment: Me too. Never mind about changes. But I do not fully understand what is happening when I click the Cell, So if you can tell me which topic to search and read about to know what's happening ?

Comment: @Ahmed take a look at [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), specifically at the **delegated events** section: _Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers_

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the elements have not been created until the click of 'input[type="submit"]' is done. Move the binding of the click of the cells into the click handler of 'input[type="submit"]':

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    var y, x, cellColor;
    //console.log("tata");

    $("#sizePicker").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function makeGrid(y, x) {
        y = Number($("#inputHeight").val());
        x = Number($("#inputWeight").val());
        $("#pixelCanvas tr").remove();
        for (i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            $("#pixelCanvas").append("<tr class='vertical'></tr>");
        }
        for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            $(".vertical").append("<td class='cell' ></td>");
        }
        $("#pixelCanvas tr td").css("background-color", "red");

        $("#pixelCanvas tr td").click(function() {
           $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. In my code, I have closed makeGrid function before the click event function so I don't need to wait for the submit button to be clicked. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: No misunderstanding. The items are not created in the DOM until makeGrid runs, and it does not run until $('input[type="submit"]') is clicked. Without the elements in the DOM the $("#pixelCanvas tr td").click(...) code ran before the elements were created in the DOM so found nothing, hence why the clicks of the cell were not being captured. The code I provide wires up the click event after the cells are created (appended) each time $('input[type="submit"]') is clicked. At the same time, your selected answer works as well. Just a matter of preference.

Comment: I totally agree with you but in the original code, makeGrid function closes before the click function.